# generar mapa de bicicletas disponibles en python

Tags: python, python-requests, mapa

tengo que generar un mapa de bicicletas disponibles con python lo unico que tengo es la tabla en formato json no se como generar el mapa

```
import requests
def get_networks(x):
    x=r.json()
    print(x)

get_networks(requests.get('http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks'))
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de mapa? ¿Dónde lo vas a mostrar?

Comment: SI te refieres a un mapa de Google Maps lo que tienes que hacer es enviar eso al frontend (un template HTML) y usar el API de Google para mostrar los pines con las coordenadas.